# Can I dump an HTML text into a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys my problem is that I have an index "link/index.html" and I want to put some specific data into an array.
The source code of the page is similar to this

```html
<tags>
.....*
</tags>
<span id="AA1"><a href="link/AA1">+</a><span title="1">AA1</span><a href="link/BB1">BB1</a><a href="link/CC1">CC1</a></span><br>
<span id="AA2"><a href="link/AA2">+</a><span title="2">AA2</span><a href="link/BB2">BB2</a><a href="link/CC2">CC2</a></span><br>
<span id="AA3"><a href="link/AA3">+</a><span title="3">AA3</span><a href="link/BB3">BB3</a><a href="link/CC3">CC3</a></span><br>
<span id="AA4"><a href="link/AA4">+</a><span title="4">AA4</span><a href="link/BB4">BB4</a><a href="link/CC4">CC4</a></span><br>
<span id="AA5"><a href="link/AA5">+</a><span title="5">AA5</span><a href="link/BB5">BB5</a><a href="link/CC5">CC5</a></span><br>
<span id="AA6"><a href="link/AA6">+</a><span title="6">AA6</span><a href="link/BB6">BB6</a><a href="link/CC6">CC6</a></span><br>
<span id="AA7"><a href="link/AA7">+</a><span title="7">AA7</span><a href="link/BB7">BB7</a><a href="link/CC7">CC7</a></span><br>
<span id="AA8"><a href="link/AA8">+</a><span title="8">AA8</span><a href="link/BB8">BB8</a><a href="link/CC8">CC8</a></span>
<tags>
.....*
</tags>
```

and i want the result to be like this

```html
$line1 = {
$variable1="AA1", $variable2="BB1", $variable3="CC1"
}
$line2 = {
$variable1="AA2", $variable2="BB2", $variable3="CC2"
}
...
```

so how can i do it with php or javascript?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It does make a difference as to whether this should be implemented in PHP, JS or both!

Comment: well i'm sorry for beeing ignorant but that's why i asked cause i needed help.

Comment: What he's saying is that it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you writing the PHP and wanting to output the HTML? Are you reading the HTML and trying to figure out how to get it into PHP variables...or something else entirely?...it really just isn't clear what you even want. You need to better think out how to communicate and describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: okay sorry, i'm reading an HTML index and trying to figure out how to get it into PHP variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to dynamically get the data into an array, you can easily do it using jquery.

My code below will output the results for you to a div. You can do what you want with the data.

```js
var myArray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = $('pre > span');
  $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
    var spans = $(row).find('a');
    var arrayObj = {};
    var n = 1;
    arrayObj[0] = $(row).find('span').text();
    $.each(spans, function(i, span) {
      arrayObj[n] = $(span).text();
      n += i;
    });
    myArray.push(arrayObj);
  });

  // this part add the vals into a dom element
  // the array objects look like this: { 1: 'text', 2: 'text' }
  // you could use an array instead of an object, or name the keys however you like.
  // I did it this way so I could easily iterate over them like an array.
  $.each(myArray, function(i, vals) {
    $('#result').append("<p>");
    $.each(vals, function(n, val) {    
      $('#result').append(val + ', ');
    });
    $('#result').append("</p>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<span id="AA1">
  <a href="link/AA1">+</a><span title="1">AA1</span><a href="link/BB1">BB1</a><a href="link/CC1">CC1</a>
</span><br>
<span id="AA2">
  <a href="link/AA2">+</a><span title="2">AA2</span><a href="link/BB2">BB2</a><a href="link/CC2">CC2</a>span><br>
<span id="AA3">
  <a href="link/AA3">+</a><span title="3">AA3</span><a href="link/BB3">BB3</a><a href="link/CC3">CC3</a>
</span>
</pre>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: sorry but, the source code isn't really mine so i can't change it i have to work with it like that.

Comment: Hmm, I can rework the code to work with what you need. It'll be a few min tho.

Comment: i'll wait, thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, I updated the answer

Comment: i have like more than 10000 line in the html file so
this code will only work with the Ids that starts with "AA" sometimes there is ids like this "E2AaNsF....."  it's kinda random. what should i do?

Comment: Hmm, are all of these rows inside a container, with nothing else?

Comment: And does that container have an Id, or some way to uniquely select it.

Comment: no, that's how the html is written, and the ids are generated randomly

Comment: Can you paste all of the html into a js fiddle for me? Http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: this is just a part of the list it's too big https://jsfiddle.net/s22gqf4b/

Comment: Can you add everything from the body tag to the start of the list? Sorry to ask for so much.

Comment: okay done : https://jsfiddle.net/s22gqf4b/1/

Comment: I updated your original fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/s22gqf4b/2/ Let me know if this gives you the result you need, or if it needs more tweaking, I'm updating my answer here as well.

Comment: thank you man you are the best.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your dev!

Answer (score 1):

Literally dump it into a PHP array like this:

```
$mainarray = array();
array_push($mainarray, array("var1"=>"AA1", "var2" => "BB1", "var3" => "CC1");
```

And then you can easily json encode it to be in a string format like this:

```
json_encode($mainarray);
```

If you're looking to do this in a loop, you can do the following:

```
for($i =0; $i<10000; $i++)
{
    array_push($mainarray, array("var1"=>"AA".$i, "var2" => "BB".$i, "var3" => "CC".$i);
}
```

The above will be in the array structure of something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    (
        var1 = 'AA0'
        var2 = 'BB0'
        var3 = 'CC0'
    ),
    [1] => 
    (
        var1 = 'AA1'
        var2 = 'BB2'
        var3 = 'CC3'
    )
    [2] => 
    (
        var1 = 'AA2'
        var2 = 'BB2'
        var3 = 'CC2'
    )
    .... And so on
)
```

Although when you think about it, you wouldn't really need an array to do this if it's sequential, just loop through the numbers when you want to echo the data out. If you're retrieving values from a database for example, you could do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "query...");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    array_push($mainarray, array("var1"=>$row['var1'], "var2" =>$row['var2'], "var3" => $row['var3']);
}
```

Comment: yeah i could of, but i have more than 10000 line in that source code that has the similar code so i can't do it Literally.

Comment: Have another read of the edited part :)

Comment: i think you didn't understand my situation here, i know how to create a json array and stuff. the  hard thing is transforming the code from tags to variable. after that, it's all easy. i need to transform each line in the source code from  <span id="AA1"><a href="link/AA1">+</a><span title="1">AA1</span><a href="link/BB1">BB1</a><a href="link/CC1">CC1</a></span> to  $var1=AA1 $var2=BB1 $var3=CC1 that's my problem not the json array. and i have like more than 10000lines